# MySQL indexing long running queries - Are keys used?

Tags: mysql

I am working on large tables of my database (mysql). Some of my queries are running more than 5 minutes. Here is an example of my query that is running slow:

```
select b.DESCRIPTION collateral_type, a.description brand, a.year,
       a.model, a.plate_number, d.description fuel, a.chassis_number,
       a.engine_number, c.description as color, insurance_name 
from lms_loan_application_collateral a inner join
     lms_collateral_type b
     on a.COLLATERAL_TYPE_ID = b.id left join
     lms_color c
     on a.color_id = c.id left join
     lms_fuel_type d
     on a.fuel_type_id = d.id inner join
     lms_loan_application e
     on e.id = a.loan_application_id inner join
     lms_dlr_dtl f
     on e.code = f.lano inner join
     lms_loanapp_dtl g
     on f.lano = g.lano
 where b.description in ('Motorcycle', 'Automotive', 'Heavy Equipment');
```

here is a mysql explain of the query

```
    +----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                                          | key                     | key_len | ref        | rows  | Extra                                              |
    +----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | g     | index | lms_loanapp_dtl_lano                                   | lms_loanapp_dtl_lano    | 23      | NULL       | 23432 | Using where; Using index                           |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | ref   | lano                                                   | lano                    | 23      | new.g.LANO |     1 | Using index                                        |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL   | lms_collateral_type_description,lms_collateral_type_id | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL       |    11 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref   | collateral_type_id                                     | collateral_type_id      | 5       | new.b.ID   |  4067 | Using index condition                              |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | ref   | lms_loan_application_id                                | lms_loan_application_id | 153     | func       |     1 | Using index condition; Using where                 |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ALL   | LMS_color_id                                           | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL       |    20 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1)     |
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | d     | ALL   | LMS_fuel_type_id                                       | NULL                    | NULL    | NULL       |     4 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
    +----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

under the key column, there are NULL values. I am not sure if mysql uses the index keys I have created.

Below is the list of indexes I created for the involved tables:

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_loan_application_collateral FROM new;

```
    +---------------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table                           | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +---------------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_loan_application_collateral |          1 | color_id            |            1 | color_id            | A         |          36 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_loan_application_collateral |          1 | fuel_type_id        |            1 | fuel_type_id        | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_loan_application_collateral |          1 | loan_application_id |            1 | loan_application_id | A         |       89493 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_loan_application_collateral |          1 | collateral_type_id  |            1 | collateral_type_id  | A         |          22 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +---------------------------------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_collateral_type FROM new;

```
    +---------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table               | Non_unique | Key_name                        | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +---------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_collateral_type |          1 | lms_collateral_type_description |            1 | DESCRIPTION | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_collateral_type |          1 | lms_collateral_type_id          |            1 | ID          | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +---------------------+------------+---------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_color FROM new;

```
    +-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table     | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_color |          1 | LMS_color_id |            1 | id          | A         |          20 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    +-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_fuel_type FROM new;

```
    +---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table         | Non_unique | Key_name         | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_fuel_type |          1 | LMS_fuel_type_id |            1 | id          | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +---------------+------------+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_loan_application FROM new;

```
    +----------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table                | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +----------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_loan_application |          1 | lmspis_id               |            1 | PIS_ID       | A         |        1878 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_loan_application |          1 | loan_type_id            |            1 | LOAN_TYPE_ID | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_loan_application |          1 | lms_loan_application_id |            1 | ID           | A         |        1878 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +----------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_dlr_dtl FROM new;

```
    +-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table       | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_dlr_dtl |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | LDDID       | A         |       90066 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_dlr_dtl |          1 | lano     |            1 | LANO        | A         |       90066 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +-------------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

SHOW INDEX FROM lms_loanapp_dtl FROM new;

```
    +-----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | Table           | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
    +-----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
    | lms_loanapp_dtl |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | LLADID      | A         |       23432 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
    | lms_loanapp_dtl |          1 | lms_loanapp_dtl_lano |            1 | LANO        | A         |       23432 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
    +-----------------+------------+----------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: It probably has something to do with your `lms_collateral_type_description` index. See this http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35821/possible-index-on-a-varchar-field-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

The tables which indicates the type as ALL does not utilise the indexes. Create indexes on id column on tables represents in c and d and one index on both description and id columns on b.

```
create index ix_id on lms_color(id);
create index ix_id on lms_fuel_type(id); 
create index ix_description_id on lms_collateral_type(description,id);
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is using ALL for your `WHERE` because of low cardinality. So MySQL thinks it is cheaper to just doing table scan over 11 entries than using binary search with index.

The real problem is that you do not filter using column whose index has higher cardinality (`lms_loanapp_dtl_lano` and `collateral_type_id`).